# "I never lie" - employee survey question

Tags: interviewing

A recent recruitment employee profile survey question: "I never lie." - do you agree or not with this statement. (Note that the question/statement is absolute and has no context attached to it.)

I answered honestly - "I Disagree" - as I am sure in the course of my life I have either told lies or exaggerations which have been taken as lies.

As an employer reviewing responses to this question, in particular my response, what would be the likely reaction/result? (This is an IT job, not the priesthood or bar exam.)

I would hope the employer's response would be "Fair enough, at least he is honest." or is this naive and I have just blown any chance of progressing my application?

Comment: You're damned if you do and damned if you don't. Why would an employer even ask this question? What could they possibly expect to learn about a candidate? This reminds of the psych test I took in high school to try to work at Blockbuster.

Comment: @jcmack: If anything, I'd think that saying you never lie _suggests_ that they are lying on the interview in order to look good.

Comment: It's a psychological profiling question. It's used so that the person evaluating the survey can gauge how honest you were in filling it out. Saying you never lie is a red flag.

Comment: @TinMan and thus the question is a waste of time.

Comment: @Crossedtheriverstyx Granted, it is, but so are a lot of these "gotcha" style questions. "What's your biggest flaw?" - "Oh, I guess I sometimes *work too hard*" / "Where do you see yourself in 5 years?" - "Oh, *right here, climbing the ladder if possible*"  The interviewers will still ask them, so it's still useful knowing how to answer for maximum "effect."

Comment: I always lie is more interesting

Comment: @Flater That's too broad to me. It isn't my business if the candidate lies in their personal life, but it is my business if their lies impact the business. You would rather hire someone who admits that they do lie and could lie to you about taking sick days, project deadlines, amount of work they versus someone else, etc? Aren't you condoning lying on the job if you willing extend an offer to someone who admits that they do lie? At the same time, you don't want to hire someone who says they don't lie, because that is likely a lie itself. I don't see what you gain from this question at all.

Comment: @jcmack Admitting to having lied is not the same as condoning lying. None of the things you infer are part of the actual question that is asked. But if you're gaming the system (trying to really get the job and willing to lie for it), you're going to be making those inferences and therefore claim you've never lied. The point is, everyone has lied at one point in their life. Claiming you haven't is a blatant lie for the sake of not losing face. So eone who says yes is therefore lying for the sake of not losing face, which is not a good trait in an employee.

Comment: @Flater I think you missed my point. The point is that there isn't a right answer, because the answer is inherently subjective. You can try to game the system, but you don't know what the system wants. The OP should run far away from employers that think that these types of question reveal some inherent tendency.

Comment: @jcmack I suspect in most cases, the system really just wants a way to filter out 1,000 potential applicants into 10 applicants who actually filled out the survey b/c the system does not have enough time to talk to all 1,000 potential applicants.

Answer (score 13):

The correct answer is of course "I lie".  That said, any company that puts a question like that to an interviewee is likely to be hell on earth to work for.

Comment: +1 Exactly, OP missed the correct answer... get out now

Comment: I don't object to the question, I question the intent behind it and seek insight from possible employers/interviewers who would ask or have this question asked, specifically what do they infer from the answer?

Comment: I wouldn't rush with the conclusions like "hell on earth". It's likely that the question was introduced by an HR person and it really does not reveal anything about the company culture.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic it reveals that the company culture allows HR to come up with ludicrous policies, such as asking such inane questions.

Comment: @Crossedtheriverstyx Perhaps it's my personal experience with big companies, but at most places I worked HR has its own culture that does not reflect what is happening in other departments at all.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic my experience has been the opposite.  One thing you'll see posted here frequently is the phrase **HR IS NOT YOUR FRIEND**

Comment: @Crossedtheriverstyx. With that I agree, but don't see how it contradicts my statement that HR department's culture is not representative of other departments.

Answer (score 6):

Answer "I lie"

If you answer "I lie" then they know that you know you are a liar.

If you answer "I don't lie" then they know you lied to them.

"I don't lie" is worse.

Answer (score 0):

> I have just blown any chance of progressing my application?

No, I believe you increased your chances by replying "I disagree" to "I never lie".

> I question the intent behind it and seek insight from possible employers/interviewers who would ask or have this question asked, specifically what do they infer from the answer? ([comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113588/i-never-lie-employee-survey-question#comment353718_113594))

Put yourself in the HR position, **if you read the answer "I agree"**, would you be inclined to hire that person? No matter how serious and honest he/she claims to be, this would either indicate:

1. not paying enough attention to the question being asked or the answers provided or...
2. willfully lied in order to improve hiring chances...

On the other hand, if the rest of the answers indicated that you should hire this person, it would be interesting to challenge that person to know if he/she understands the concept of, for example, *white lies*.

This would tell how this person could affect the performance of other workers or the work environment itself by not accepting any lies or by refusing to lie in certain necessary situations.